# A variation of splay tree

Tags: algorithm, splay-tree

I want to create a splay tree with these two additional rules:

[image]

does these two rules change the access time of splay tree([access lemma](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f05/www/documents/splay-trees.txt)) ?

if no , how can I prove it?

Comment: If no, then you should be able to mimic the proof given in the document that you linked to, which uses as a potential function the sums of the logs of the ranks of the nodes and bounds the sum of potential changes for a splay. The customary splay operations are carefully chosen so that this sum telescopes.

Comment: If yes, then it may be instructive to understand why rotate-to-root, the scheme that inspired splay trees, didn't work.